# How to place picture in top left corner of device?

Tags: image, position, coronasdk

CORONA SDK

i think this is a config problem.

when i open corona, i typed in 720 and 1280 for the w h dimensions because i wanted to change my view primarily to the galaxy s 3.

is this necessary? can i just click phone preset and continue? then change my view to whatever device i want??

the problem is that when i type:

```
place1 = display.newImage("room.jpg")
```

the image does show up.

now, i would like the image to be modified.
I would like its width to be half of the screen.
I would like its height to be 1/5 of the screen.

i tried some things, but nothing worked.

then i replaced that:

```
place1 = display.newImageRect("room.jpg" , display.contentWidth/2 , 
display.contentHeight/2)
```

but this results in the image being pushed to far to the left and upward that you can hardly see it!!

How do I get the image to appear, modify its dimensions, and place it in the top left hand corner of the screen without it being cropped off??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i am specifically mapping things out for the galaxy s3. so the first step is to enter that device's screen dimensions into the config or into the preset area as soon as you open a new project in corona. 720 x 1280.

Then be sure to change the view from iPhone (default) to galaxy s3 to use all of your content space area because iphone is way to small.

So.
I started with this:

### **STEP 1**

```
local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720, 1280)
place1.x = 720
place1.y = 1280
```

which yielded

[image]

then i told myself, corona is going by the center of the image, so if I can get the center of the image to be in the middle of the screen/display....because right now, the center of the image is at 720, 1280, the last coordinate available in my set config area for galaxy s3. (the bottom right corner)

so i did this

### **STEP 2**

```
local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720, 1280)
place1.x = 720/2
place1.y = 1280/2
```

which yielded

[image]

keep in mind that i purposely made the dimensions of the image 720 by 1280 to fill up the screen entirely, so i can get a sense of position.

then, i told myself i need to now alter the dimensions of the image, i want this to be 1/2 of the x distance of the screen, and 1/5 of the y distance of the screen.

so i did this

### **STEP 3**

```
local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720/2, 1280/5)
place1.x = 720/2
place1.y = 1280/2
```

which yielded

[image]

at this point, i have the image centered in the middle of the screen, with my desired dimensions, all i have to do is get it in the top left hand corner, because there will be other rooms in a grid fashion. (ex. another room will fit in the space to the right of this image once its correctly placed)

so i did this

### **STEP 4**

```
local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720/2, 1280/5)
place1.x = 720/2 - (.5*place1.contentWidth)
place1.y = 1280/2
```

which yielded
[image]

just by looking at it, you can tell that if its in the center, you need to subtract half of the image's x distance for it to be on the left edge of the phone- the point of this experiment. this works because i centered the image and made it fit the entire screen first. now all distances to the phone edges are relative to the image's x and y distance. :DD

continuing.,,

to get the picture to the top edge

i did this

### **STEP 5**

```
local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720/2, 1280/5)
place1.x = 720/2 - (.5*place1.contentWidth)
place1.y = 1280/2 - (2*place1.contentHeight)
```

which yielded

[image]

because i needed to subtract twice the y distance of the image.

and *voila!*

the image is in the top left hand corner and stretched to my desired dimensions. now everything is relative to the image's distances, for example if i wanted another room below this one, i could (starting from step 4), subtract ONE y distance of the image instead of twice that distance.

like this

```
local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720/2, 1280/5)
place1.x = 720/2 - (.5*place1.contentWidth)
place1.y = 1280/2 - (2*place1.contentHeight)

local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", 720/2, 1280/5)
place1.x = 720/2 - (.5*place1.contentWidth)
place1.y = 1280/2 - (1*place1.contentHeight)
```

and this yields

[image]

These:

```
object.contentWidth
object.contentHeight
```

come in handy when trying to move the image left or right a certain fraction of the its own width or height.

The previous way helps to understand positioning images by using the default center reference point of an image, and starting by positioning that image in the center of the display!

ANOTHER EASIER WAY:
change the image's reference point to the top left reference point, then control things from there. in this case, the image's x and y position would be 0 putting it in the top left hand corner of the SCREEN and then from there change the dimensions to 1/5 of display's height and 1/2 of the display's width. 
:D

Something like this is much more efficient:

```
_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

local place1 = display.newImageRect("map/1.billiard.jpg", _W/2, _H/5)
place1:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
place1.x = 0
place1.y = 0
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Comment: you can accept my answer if your problem is solve by clicking the check image at the left of my answer

Answer (score 1):

it pushes from far left and upward because the reference point of the image is pointing to center i think you need some calculation on it to make it at the top left of your screen i have created some calculation for me to my image to make the reference point at the topleft hope this can help you

```
local place1 = display.newImage("Images/place1.png", 0,0,true)
place1 .xScale = (0.5 * place1 .contentWidth)/place1 .contentWidth
place1 .yScale = place1 .xScale
place1 .x = place1 .contentWidth / 2
place1 .y = place1 .contentHeight / 2
```

just change value of place1.x to make the desire position that you want

Comment: This almost resolved the issue!! now how can i change not the position of the picture, but the dimensions????? like i would like the x distance of the pic to be 1/2 of the screen and the y distance of the pic to be 1/5 of the screen? the position is in the top left corner though, this worked. but how can i alter the dimensions of the actual picture?